# Creating a new variable using a series with duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, time-series

So I have a data set where my output is:

```
gdp = pd.read_csv(r"gdpproject.csv", 
encoding="ISO-8859-1")
gdp.head(2)
gdp.tail(2)
```

This gives me output of:

```
Country.Name    Indicator.Name  2004    2005    
0   World   GDP 5.590000e+13    5.810000e+13
1   World   Health  5.590000e+13    5.810000e+13
086 Zimbabwe    GDP per capita  8.681564e+02    8.082944e+02
089 Zimbabwe    Population  1.277751e+07    1.294003e+07
```

So immediately you notice that each country has multiple indicators.

What I am trying to do is create a new indicator from two of the current indicators. And create it for each unique country.

```
for i in series(gdp['Country.Name']):
gdp['Military Spending'] = 100 / gdp['Military percent of GDP'] * 
gdp['GDP']
```

It is giving me this error message:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-d817ea1522fc> in <module>()
----> 1 for i in series(gdp1['Country.Name']):
  2     gdp1['Military Spending'] = 100 / gdp1['Military percent of GDP'] * 
gdp1['GDP']

NameError: name 'series' is not defined
```

How do I get this series to work? I also had tried it as simply

```
for i in gdp['Country.Name']
```

but still get an error message.

Help please!

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have following input `Dataframe` (Note that in your example data `Military percent of GDP` was not there):

```
>>> gdp
  Country.Name           Indicator.Name          2004          2005
0        World                      GDP  5.590000e+13  5.810000e+13
1        World  Military percent of GDP  2.100000e+00  2.300000e+00
2     Zimbabwe                      GDP  1.628900e+10  1.700000e+10
3     Zimbabwe  Military percent of GDP  2.000000e+00  2.100000e+00
```

You can then create auxiliary dataframes `df_gdp` and `df_mpgdp` with data from `2004` and `2005` for `GDP` and `Military percent of GDP` respectively. Then you can create `df_msp` which will contain your new `Indicator.Name` called `Military Spending`, and finally append its results to the original `Dataframe`. Note that we need to `reset_index` in certain situations to ensure the calculations are done with the expected indexes.

Below code should work for what you are aiming for:

```
import pandas as pd
gdp = pd.DataFrame( [
["World",  "GDP",  5.590000e+13,  5.810000e+13], 
["World",  "Military percent of GDP",  2.1, 2.3], 
["Zimbabwe",  "GDP",  16289e6, 17000e6], 
["Zimbabwe",  "Military percent of GDP",  2, 2.1]])
gdp.columns = ["Country.Name", "Indicator.Name", "2004", "2005"]

df_gdp = gdp[gdp["Indicator.Name"] == "GDP"]
df_mpgdp = gdp[gdp["Indicator.Name"] == "Military percent of GDP"]

df_msp = pd.DataFrame()
df_msp["Country.Name"] = df_gdp["Country.Name"].reset_index(drop=True)
df_msp["Indicator.Name"] = "Military Spending"
df_msp["2004"] = 100 / df_mpgdp[["2004"]].reset_index(drop=True) *  df_gdp[["2004"]].reset_index(drop=True)
df_msp["2005"] = 100 / df_mpgdp[["2005"]].reset_index(drop=True) *  df_gdp[["2005"]].reset_index(drop=True)

gdp_out = gdp.append(df_msp)
gdp_out = gdp_out.sort_values(["Country.Name", "Indicator.Name"])
gdp_out = gdp_out.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Finally output `Dataframe` would result in:

```
>>> gdp_out
  Country.Name           Indicator.Name          2004          2005
0        World                      GDP  5.590000e+13  5.810000e+13
1        World        Military Spending  2.661905e+15  2.526087e+15
2        World  Military percent of GDP  2.100000e+00  2.300000e+00
3     Zimbabwe                      GDP  1.628900e+10  1.700000e+10
4     Zimbabwe        Military Spending  8.144500e+11  8.095238e+11
5     Zimbabwe  Military percent of GDP  2.000000e+00  2.100000e+00
```